# What happened to displacement and bump?

Tags: modeling, materials

I am following this tutorial up to 8.24 min, where it´s about *displacement and bump* under material properties. I am using blender 3.0.[image: teddy]

You can see it on the right lower corner.
Is that setting anywhere else to be found?

EDIT:
I came back to that matter to eventually find that same problem again. The whole setup seems to have changed in 3.1.[image: troll] I don´t seem to find ***Displacement and Bump***. I have Cycles turned on. What can I do?

Comment: You need to be in Cycles

Comment: Ok thanks. Didn´t consider this.